# Unit testing against (outdated) woocommerce 6.9.2 - require the full code base of this version including tests, test setup (bootstrap.php)

Tags: unit-testing, woocommerce

**Situation:**

*I am currently helping out with a woocommerce based project in a wordpress environment and fixing a bunch of unit tests which I have written for a custom plugin a couple of years ago.*

The plugin / the unit tests were developed for **woocommerce version 4.1.0** and the current version being installed is **woocommerce 6.9.2**

Due to restrictions which are out of my control, I have to stick with (outdated) version 6.9.2 (I am aware of the security implications, but this is just the way it is, and I have agreed to fix the tests / codebase for the version 6.9.2 – as a next step, woocommerce will be updated to the current version, but as I said, I have no influence to speed this up).

To implement my tests I have used the woocommerce test bootstrap file (*in version 4.1.0 the path is … /tests/bootstrap.php*), adapted some environment vars,…. and implemented my tests.

Having a look at the current codebase of woocommerce I discovered that the structure of the test setup seems to have changed quite a bit since version 4.1.0 (documented in the changes to the bootstrap.php file, some new mocked implementations are required,….)

What I need is a full codebase of woocommerce version 6.9.2 including the whole test setup, the matching bootstrap.php file, and all other changes, so I can adapt my test setup to be able to test internally against the currently used version 6.9.2.

Taking a look at the 6.9.2 version in the git repo (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/releases/tag/6.9.2)

one can see the actual tests and the test bootstrap is missing.

**My question:**

Does anyone have an idea / link where / howto get a codebase for version 6.9.2 as it was when it was released (with the unit tests, the test setup – meaning basically the required mock implementations and the bootstrap.php file) so I can repair my existing codebase and my unit tests ?

As this is neither an issue nor a bug or feature request, I don’t feel like spamming the git repo with this question; maybe one of the woocommerce gurus here has handled a similar problem in the past and can give me some advice.

Thanks and kind regards,

Matthias